# Were these the last words of Trotsky's assasin?

Tags: history, quotes

[Ramon Mercader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ram%C3%B3n_Mercader) assassinated Leon Trotsky on August 20th 1940. Ramon was jailed by the Mexican government, but was released in 1961. He died in Cuba of lung cancer in 1978. Wikipedia claims his last words were said to have been:

> "I hear it always. I hear the scream. I know he's waiting for me on the other side."

This seems awfully dramatic in my opinion, and Wikipedia's source for the claim, a [Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/sep/13/trotsky-ice-axe-murder-mexico-city) article about the ice pick Trotsky was killed with, has the same quote as Wikipedia and doesn't say where it got the quote from.

After a couple Google searches, I was unable to come up with any more information on the origin of this quote, so I'm wondering if anyone knows where this quote came from, and if it's authentic.

Comment: According to the book [The mind of an assassin](https://books.google.com/books?id=TiTp3Bz3SbAC&pg=PA31102&lpg=PA31102&dq="screamed+in+such+a+way+that+i+will+never+forget+it") Mercader said "[Trotsky] screamed in such a way that I will never forget it as long as I live." But this book was published in 1959, well before Mercader died.